# Boxes, balls, conditional probability, Bayes' theorem and Law of total probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Please help me to validate my solution for the following problem:

> We have $2n-1$ boxes. There are $i$ white and $2n-i$ black balls in
>   box number $i$, where $i=1,2,\ldots,2n-1$. First we chose a box
>   randomly with equal probabilities. Then we chose 2 balls from the box
>   without putting them back. In which case probability that we have chosen box
>   number $n$ is higher:
>
> 1. Balls have the same color;
> 2. Balls have different colors?

My attempt:

Let $A$ is event "Balls have the same color", $B$ is event "Balls have different colors", $H_n$ is event "box number n was chosen". So basically we have to compare $\mathbb{P}(H_n|A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(H_n|B)$. How do we compute them? We use Bayes' theorem which claims that $$\mathbb{P}(H_n|A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(H_n)\mathbb{P}(A|H_n)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}.$$ How do we compute $\mathbb{P}(A)$? We use the Law of total probability which tells us that $$\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}\mathbb{P}(H_i)\mathbb{P}(A|H_i).$$
It is easy to see, that $\mathbb{P}(H_i)=\frac{1}{2n-1}$ What about $\mathbb{P}(A|H_i)$? Of course, $\mathbb{P}(A|H_i)$ + $\mathbb{P}(B|H_i)=1$, so let us compute "easier" probability. For me $\mathbb{P}(B|H_i)$ looks easier. So $$\mathbb{P}(B|H_i)={i \choose 1}\cdot{2n - i \choose 1} / {2n \choose 2}=\frac{i(2n-i)}{n(2n-1)}.$$ Now let us compute $$\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}\frac{i(2n-i)}{n(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{n(2n-1)^2}(2n\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i - \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i^2).$$ Since $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i=(2n-1)n$$
and $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i^2=\frac{(2n-1)2n(2(2n-1)+1)}{6}=\frac{n(2n-1)(4n-1)}{3}$$ we get $$\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{1}{n(2n-1)^2}(2n^2(2n-1)-\frac{n(2n-1)(4n-1)}{3})=\frac{2n-\frac{4n-1}{3}}{2n-1}=\frac13\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}.$$
Quick check : if $n=1$ then we have one white and one black ball in one box, so we must have $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$ and the formula gives the same probability. Now let us compute $$\mathbb{P}(A)=1-\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac13\frac{4n-4}{2n-1},$$ $$\mathbb{P}(B|H_n)=\frac{n}{2n-1},\ \  \mathbb{P}(A|H_n)=1-\mathbb{P}(B|H_n)=\frac{n-1}{2n-1},$$ $$\mathbb{P}(H_n|A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(H_n)\mathbb{P}(A|H_n)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{1}{2n-1}\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\frac{3(2n-1)}{4(n-1)}=\frac{3}{4(2n-1)},n \neq 1,$$ $$\mathbb{P}(H_n|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(H_n)\mathbb{P}(B|H_n)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}=\frac{1}{2n-1}\frac{n}{2n-1}\frac{3(2n-1)}{2n+1}=\frac{3n}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}.$$ Now since $$\frac14<\frac{n}{2n+1}, n \geq 2$$ we have $$\mathbb{P}(H_n|A) < \mathbb{P}(H_n|B),\  n \neq 1.$$

Thanks a lot for your help. I hope my solution is correct, but I have just started to learn this material and I still do not feel myself 100% confident about my understanding/calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution looks good to me!

Comment: Terrific, thanks a lot!

Comment: Name checks out.